# ¿Cómo obligo que haga salto de linea las ecuaciones en columnas con paracol?

Tags: latex

Código Latex

```latex
Consideremos el conjunto $\wp(\{1,2\})$ bajo la relación de $\subseteq$.

    \begin{paracol}{2}
        Los elementos de $\wp(\{1,2\})$ son $\emptyset,\ \{1\},\ \{2\}$ y $\{1,2\}$ y la relación binaria $\subseteq$ consiste de los siguientes pares ordenados:

        $\{ (\emptyset,\ \emptyset);\ (\{1\},\ \{1\});\ (\{2\},\ \{2\});\ (\{1,\ 2\},\ \{1,\ 2\});\ (\emptyset,\ \{1\});\ (\emptyset,\ \{2\});\  (\emptyset,\ \{1,\ 2\});\ (\{1\},\ \{1,\ 2\});\ (\{2\},\ \{1,\ 2\}) \}$

        \switchcolumn

        El Diagrama de Hasse correspondiente es:

        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{unidades/img/ejemplo1.png}
        \end{center}

        Note que $\emptyset$ es un predecesor de $\{1,\ 2\}$, pero no un predecesor inmediato de $\{1,\ 2\}$.
    \end{paracol}
```

Resultado generado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que no "transpase" la imagen que coloco y haga saltos de lineas cuando sean necesarios una vez llegado al tope de la columna

Comment: Hola! Si agrega su header, es posible dar una respuesta ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that))

Comment: me temo que ya no es posible ya que no dispongo del archivo

Answer (score 1):

Divide la fórmula con $ en los lugares donde son posibles los saltos de línea, de esta forma haces unidades más pequeñas que pueden pasar a las líneas siguientes y no se te salen por los márgenes.